# Subtract in Union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data, where I want to generate the last row "on the fly" from the first two:

| Group | 1yr | 2yrs | 3yrs | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Port | 19 | -15 | 88 | 1/1/2020 | arp |
| Bench | 10 | -13 | 66 | 1/1/2020 | arb |
| Diff | 9 | 2 | 22 |  |  |

I am trying to subtract the `Port` & `Bench` returns and have the difference on the new row. How can I do this?

Here's my code so far:

```
Select 
date
            Group,
            Code,
          1 yr returnp,
          2 yrs returnp,
          3yrs return
From timetable
union
 Select   
date,
           Group,
           Code,
          1 yr returnb,
          2 yrs returnb,
          3yrs returnb
From timetable
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at all. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: No this isn't my attempt, I just added the query to show the columns i need to subtract which is 1yr returnp - 1year returnb

Comment: Also what is the criteria determining which is the subtrahend?

Comment: This is what I tried:   Select date, 
            Group,
            Code,
          1 yr returnp - 1 yr returnb
          2 yrs returnp – 2yrs returnb
          3yrs returnp – 3yrs returnb
From timetable a
Join timetable b 
On a.group = b.group
WHERE a.DateAsOf = (SELECT MAX(DateAsOf)
                        FROM timetable)

Comment: The syntax is invalid, so you can't have used that. At least remove your errors before posting.

Comment: Please before you post any more code in comments or the question, build a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) and make sure the code you say you're running actually runs.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that a UNION ALL in concert with a conditional aggregation should do the trick

Note the `sum()` is wrapped in an `abs()` to match desired results

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
Union All 
Select [Group] = 'Diff'
      ,[1yr]   = abs(sum([1yr]  * case when [Group]='Bench' then -1 else 1 end))
      ,[2yrs]  = abs(sum([2yrs] * case when [Group]='Bench' then -1 else 1 end))
      ,[3yrs]  = abs(sum([3yrs] * case when [Group]='Bench' then -1 else 1 end))
      ,[date]  = null
      ,[code]  = null
 from YourTable
```

Results

```
Group   1yr   2yrs  3yrs    date        code
Port    19    -15   88      2020-01-01  arp
Bench   10    -13   66      2020-01-01  arb
Diff    9     2     22      NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is always 2 rows, something like this would work

```
SELECT * FROM timetable
UNION ALL
SELECT
  MAX(1yr) - MIN(1yr),
  MAX(2yrs) - MIN(2yrs),
  MAX(3yrs) - MIN(3yrs),
  null,
  null,
FROM timetable
```